# How to auto refresh VLC media library?

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player

Is there a way to set up the VLC media library so that when I add a file to the media library folder, the file will automatically be added to the media library without me having to touch VLC?  In other words, I don't want to have to click on media library and "add file" or restart VLC or the like.

Comment: Have you searched the command line options for launching VLC via command line? There are some hidden nuggets of goodness down at that level.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a perfect answer for this problem but probably the best solution at the moment is to go to %AppData%\Roaming\vlc\vlcrc. Then open vlrc with a decent text editor like notepad++ and hit control+F and search recursive.

Change from #recursive=collapse to recursive=expands and hit control+S to save. Then reopen VLC and in media library add the top folder or folders (music,video,podcast,etc) to the media library. These folders should be blue and when you double click on them they turn gray and will begin listing their child folders and files automatically.

You'll still need to update the playlist manually but now you can let VLC do all the work for you by simply adding the top folder again and double clicking on it. It will then give you an updated playlist and then you can simply "remove from playlist" the old version of the top folder.

Obviously this still isn't ideal but I suspect this updating could be made automatic each time VLC loads through a plugin and I wouldn't be surprised if such a plugin already exists.

See [Automatically Expanding Media Library Folders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhCGZQPD4zM).

Answer (score -1):

We'll try scrolling down,if you do that, you will see a circle loading icon,let it roll through,then check your videos